# Compare year to year revenue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot to compare year to year revenue, but I can't get it to work and don't understand why.

Consider my df:

```
 df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2017-10-01"), by = "month"),
                 rev = rnorm(22, 150, sd = 20))

    df %>% 
      separate(date, c("Year", "Month", "Date")) %>% 
      filter(Month <= max(Month[Year == "2017"])) %>% 
      group_by(Year, Month) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = rev, fill = Year)) + 
      geom_line()
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

I don't really understand why this isn't working. What I want is two lines that go from January to October.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2017-10-01"), by = "month"),
                 rev = rnorm(22, 150, sd = 20))

df %>% 
  separate(date, c("Year", "Month", "Date")) %>% 
  filter(Month <= max(Month[Year == "2017"]))  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = rev, color = Year, group = Year)) + 
  geom_line()
```

it was just the grouping which gone wrong due to the type of variables, it might be usefull if you use `lubridate` for the dates (also a tidyverse package)

```
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.factor(year(date)), Month = month(date)) %>% 
  filter(Month <= max(Month[Year == "2017"])) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = rev, color = Year)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `ggplot2` is confused because it doesn't recognise the format of your `Month` column, which is a character in this case.  Try converting it to numeric:

```
... +
ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Month), y = rev, colour = Year)) +
....
```

Note that I replace the word `fill` with `colour`, which I believe makes more sense for this chart:

[image: sample output]

Btw, I'm not sure the `group_by` statement is adding anything.  I get the same chart with or without it.